# Starting with angular material design

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've been trying to use Angular Material Design for one week now with no success. I spent my time studying HTML/CSS, JavaScript, and AngularJS to understand what is going wrong, but I still don't know what the problem is.

Basically what I have tried is the *"Getting Started"* section of the [Google Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/getting-started) website but none of them worked with me:

I've tried to copy its [Github Starter Project](https://github.com/angular/material-start) but I got this as result:

*edit: sorry my account is new and I can't post images yet, but it is a print screen of my website not even running angular ![My Result][3] .*

I've also tried to copy its simple Hello World example, but I got very similar problems.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I think it is very simple. I have a feeling that I'm not importing the right CSS/JS.

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav){
  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
    $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
  };
 
}]);
```

```css
.menuBtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
} 
md-toolbar h1 {
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: auto;
}
md-list .md-button {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.visually-hidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0; 
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

/* Using Data-URI converted from svg until <md-icon> becomes available 
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons
*/
.menuBtn {
  background: transparent url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat  center center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/test.css">
  </head>
  <body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
      <button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="menuBtn">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$media('gt-sm')">
          
        </md-sidenav>
        <div layout="column" flex id="content">
            <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
              
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      
    <script src="JS/test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I try to re-create this exact code on [brackets][4] but when I run it in the browser, it doesn't work. Is there something else that I have to do on my code?

Comment: If you run the code in a plunkr, what exactly is not working? http://plnkr.co/edit/GqHyyJQnvNria6JdU1dN?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what isn't working for you, but as a note, if you are viewing this page from your local file system, you will need to specify `http://` or `https://` when referencing your external resources.

Currently all of your assets are being referenced like this: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.7.1/angular-material.min.css`

This might be keeping angular and everything else from loading into your page.

#### More explanation

As mentioned in the comments, what you are using is called a [Protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

> If the browser is viewing that current page in through HTTPS, then it’ll request that asset with the HTTPS protocol, otherwise it’ll typically* request it with HTTP. This prevents that awful “This Page Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items” error message in IE, keeping all your asset requests within the same protocol.

The article also mentions:

> *Of course, if you’re viewing the file locally, it’ll try to request the file with the file:// protocol.

Comment: Thats a protocol relative URL : http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @muttonUp I forgot what it was called. I will add more explanation to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it not only helped me with this problem but I've managed to fix a lot of other broken pages

Comment: @Jack sorry for the late response. It is marked as answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome, open developer tools (F12) and verify that you load the js and css files properly.